# AVAssetExportSession does not honour videocomposition instructions

Tags: ios, swift, video, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I am trying to apply AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction on an AVMutableComposition for a video. The problem is it does not honour the instruction when the video is saved using AVAssetExportSession. The weird part is, the same composition works with AVPlayer (AVPlayer honours the instruction).

Here's the code:

```
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "flame", ofType: "mp4")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url as URL)

        let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        let type = AVMediaTypeVideo
        let prefTrackID = kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid

        let sourceVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: type).first!
        let sourceAudioAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first!

        let videoCompositionTrack1 = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: type, preferredTrackID: prefTrackID)


        do {
            let range = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60,600))
            try videoCompositionTrack1.insertTimeRange(range, of: sourceVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }catch { print(error) }

        let firstTransform = videoCompositionTrack1.preferredTransform;

        let fromLayer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoCompositionTrack1)
        fromLayer.setTransform(firstTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)
        fromLayer.setCropRectangle(CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: 200, height: 200), at: kCMTimeZero)

        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.layerInstructions = [fromLayer]
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60,600))

        videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComposition!.instructions = [instruction]
        videoComposition!.renderSize = CGSize.init(width: 300, height: 300)
        videoComposition!.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)


        if(true){ // just to switch between the saving and playing modes
            var exportPath: NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("/video.mov")
            var exportUrl: NSURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: exportPath as String) as NSURL

            var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)!
            exporter.outputURL = exportUrl as URL
            exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition!

            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
            exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter.canPerformMultiplePassesOverSourceMediaData = true

            exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exportUrl as URL)
                }) { completed, error in
                    if completed {
                        print("Video is saved!")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mutableComposition)
            playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition!
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            player.play()
        }
```

[image: AVPlayer honours cropRectangle instruction]

AVPlayer honours cropRectangle instruction as seen above

[image: Saved video is same as the original video]

Saved video is same as the original video.

I am building this on iOS 9. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could this be that AVPlayer will rotate the media based on the meta data, then apply your instructions, the exporter does not, you may need to assess its transform and adjust accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sean. I am not sure what metadata are you referring to here ? I am sorry I am a noob in AVFoundation. Are you referring to the AVAsset metadata ?

Comment: In the AVAsset there are transforms that tell the player to rotate it, when you use exporter you need to get and perform these transforms yourself

Comment: But isn't AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction supposed to do the transforms, avplayer or exporter? And that is applied in both cases. Also I am not rotating the asset, just cropping.

Comment: Yes but you have to tell it if you want it to transform something

Comment: So is it like a flag that needs to be set on the exporter that tells it to honour the layer instructions? How do I tell the exporter to do so?  Is there an example you can point me to ? I pretty much followed apple's way to export it https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html

Comment: No it's on the AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction

Comment: it doesnt look like there is anything in AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction that could help here. https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmutablevideocompositionlayerinstruction

Comment: setTransofrm: ....its like your not even trying ...

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is setTransform on AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction would work but not setCropRectangle in case of exporter? So that means its a bug on apple's side coz both of them are part of AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction. I tried `fromLayer.setTransform(CGAffineTransform.init().rotated(by: 0.785), at: kCMTimeZero)` and it does not honour that as well.

Comment: no, crop is for cropping, transform for... transforming (rotating, translating, size) If you look at the AVAsset it has a preferredTransform, from what I remember you use fromLayer.setTransform(asset.preferredTransform)

Comment: Like I mentioned in my last comment, setTransform is not being honoured as well. Also, we are still not on the same page after so many back and forths, and if you think you can make it work on your side, please do that and add that as the answer. There is a bounty on this, it will be all yours.

Comment: the original video looks 16:9 so why are you trying to crop it, crop is reducing the size of the viewable area, all you need to do is apply the transform and renderSize needs to be the output screensize.. if you give me a link to the video I will do it on my lunch in a few hours

Comment: I found the problem. It is with this line ` NSTemporaryDirectory().appendingFormat("/video.mov") ` . It seems like the exporter.outputUrl doesn't override if a file already exists at an outputUrl. If I change `video.mov` to something else, I can see the layer instructions being exported in the video.  All the instructions work including setCropRectangle and transforms. So all this while I was seeing my first ever exported video, which didnt contain any intructions probably.

Comment: Ha, I see, you should have been seeing an error saying it could not complete ?, thank fully its sorted, need any more just reply here I guess

Comment: Yep, exporter status contains failed. My bad. Anyways, thanks for your effort in thinking about this with me. If you would like, please write an answer here, and take the bounty. I cant get it back and if noone answers, it will be gone.

Comment: Have done :D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applying a transform on a `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` you can get the desired transform needed from the `AVAsset`'s `preferredTransform`

EDIT: Turns out it was an export error for existing file, either use a unique name when trying to write e.g.

```
String(Date) + ".mov"
```

Or delete before trying to write

Comment: That is not the correct answer. Can you add the correct answer that solved this? Otherwise people are gonna downvote this answer in the future.